# How to stop page refresh on form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which automatically refreshes the page on submit, I have tried adding:

`onSubmit="return false;"` to the form element, but then the form just stops and nothing happens when you click submit.

I wouldnt mind the page refresh so much but the form is at the bottom of the page and the refresh kicks you back to the top. So I tried this approach:

`<form name='test' method='POST' action="index.php" onSubmit="window.scrollTo(5000,500);">`

This works for a split second but then something else overrides it (not sure what)

I have also tried using php: `header.location` just to get a "headers have already been sent" error.

The site in question can be seen [here](http://www.kg-stores.com/kineticgroup_website_redesign_working/), and the form is at the very bottom.

The only two jquery libraries I am using that I could foresee any conflicts with are nicescroll and (more likely) waypoints, but i dug through them both and couldn't find any conflicting issues.

If anyone knows of a way to keep the functionality of the form but stop the refresh of the page, that would be wonderful
Thanks

EDIT:  After reading the answers below, it looks like I will have to use ajax to acomplish this,  I have absolutely no experience with ajax, so I will see how that goes.

Comment: That's not how form submits work. When you submit a form it passes the data (`form data`) to the page identified in the `action` attribute via HTTP request. Period. If you want the page to not "refresh" you have to use AJAX.

Comment: Unless you use AJAX, you are going to have to do a new HTTP request to get the info to the server. Maybe I am not understanding something?

Comment: Use ajax or give the form an id and set the hash in the action. Example: `<form name="test" method="POST" action="index.php#myform" id="myform">`  The latter will still refresh but bring the user back to the form.

Comment: @Walialu I guess a more appropriate title would have been: how to keep page scroll position after refresh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need to go through of way of ***AJAX*** submission in that case. In that case, you can use jQuery ***[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajax)*** method to do that. A sample below:

***HTML***

```
<form name='test' method='POST' action="index.php">
```

***jQuery***

```
$('form[name=test]').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.scrollTo(5000,500);

   // a sample AJAX request
   $.ajax({
     url : this.action,
     type : this.method,
     data : $(this).serialize(),
     success : function(response) {

     }
   });
});
```

Here, ***[`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault)*** is for stop page refresh on form submit.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of even using the form element?

Comment: Tried the jquery example and it still wont submit the form, i have zero experience with ajax but it looks like i'll have to go that route. Thanks for the head start

Answer (score 3):

Why not submit the form to a hidden IFRAME?

```
<iframe name="myiframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<form name='test' method='POST' action="index.php" target="myiframe">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: tried this and the php form validation doesn't seem to work with this method

Answer (score 0):

What about using AJAX instead of a normal form submit?